# How isn't propertyChanged null although we don't initialize it?

Tags: c#, events, xamarin.forms, inotifypropertychanged, eventhandler

On Xamarin.Forms I implement INotifyPropertyChanged and it works fine.

There is something I don't understand though:
PropertyChanged is a an event, which means it is a delegate.
Before we invoke event/delegate we need them to point on some function/eventHundler.

How is it, that here we declare an event, we don't set it to point on
any function and everything works well! How come it is not null, although we've never initialize it.

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
{
   var changed = PropertyChanged;
    if (changed == null)   //It seems for me, this should be null for ever.  
       return;
     changed.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

Comment: if there are any listeners to the PropertyChanged event, it will not be null.  If you are using this class for data binding, then the UI will automatically subscribe to the event.

Comment: This null check is not what you think it is. *"we've never initialize it"* - event is not a property or a field. When you define `event` you actually define special property with [add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/add)/[remove](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/remove) accessors on top of multicast delegate, which is always not null. Event null check is simply a way to check for subscribers, I never worry how exactly it's implented tbh.

Comment: @Sinatr  This is exactly the thing. I didn't subscribe no one to this event. This is the reason I except this will be always null.

Comment: @S Itzik... You did not subscribe to it... yes... But the controls subscribe to it. Thats how binding works.

Comment: **you** did not subscribe to it.  The whole point of using data binding is that a LOT of magic happens without **you** having to do that work.  The data binding mechanism is subscribing to that event.

Comment: `PropertyChanged` event is special. It's used internally by [bindings](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop-wpf/data/data-binding-overview). If binding has (depends on [BindingMode](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.data.bindingmode)) to monitor for source changes, then at run-time it attempts to resolve what mechanisms it can use to achieve that. If it finds that source implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`, then it will subscribe to `PropertyChanged` event. So at run-time it won't be `null`. At some point binding will unsubscribe, so it will be `null`.

Comment: @Sinatr Can you please write it as an answer and not as a comment?

Answer (score 0):

Expression `someEvent == null` will return true if **event has not been subscribed to**. You need to perform this check because otherwise, you may get a `NullReferenceException`. For more info on events check [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/events/).

**Edit:**

Internal code of Xamarin.Forms subscribes to your event. This way when you invoke the event Xamarin.Forms knows that value of some property has been updated and can update it in the form.

Comment: @ Yes, and what I say is, that I didn't subscribe no one to this event. Therefore (also as you wrote) this event should be null...but it isn't.

Comment: @SItzik Internal code of Xamarin.Forms subscribes to your event. This way when you invoke the event Xamarin.Forms knows that value of some property has been updated and can update it in the form

Comment: @AWhiteFox, please [edit] it into the answer. It seems to be thing OP is asking about.